# Plotting a reciprocal of a sine function in tikz + pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

This is my code at the moment:

```
% Rest of document omitted brevity...
\subsection*{f(x) = cosec(x)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
  mark=none,
  domain=0:360,
  samples=500,
  smooth}, % All plots: 50 samples, smooth, no marks
  axis x line=middle,
  axis y line=center,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=360,
  ymin=-1,
  ymax=1,
  enlargelimits=upper] % extend the axes a bit to the right and top
  \addplot {1 / sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% Rest of document omitted brevity...
```

This looks right to me, however, when I try and compile, I get: `C:/Users/Todd/Dropbox/Homework/Notes/A-level_Maths/Core 3/Graphs/Graphs.tex:111: Dimension too large. [\end{axis}]`

When I change `\addplot {1 / sin(x)};` to `\addplot {sin(x)};` the document compiles without any issues. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are dividing one by zero.

Comment: Ahhh yes of course!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some remarks about what are you trying to achieve:

- Consider using degrees as an argument for trigonometric functions via `deg(x)`-pgfplots function.
- After using `deg(x)` the domain and range of `x`-axes should be rescaled.
- Don't forget the `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}` in document preamle. =)
- Use `cosec(x)` function instead of `1 / sin(x)`.

Finally we've got (included all, wrapped in `standalone`):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
      mark=none,
      domain=0:10,
      samples=500,
      smooth}, % All plots: 50 samples, smooth, no marks
  axis x line=middle,
  axis y line=center,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=10,
  ymin=-10,
  ymax=10,
  enlargelimits=upper] % extend the axes a bit to the right and top
  \addplot {cosec(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, It would appear that using deg(x) fixes the problem

Answer (score 6):

Problem is on `x=k*pi`, `1/sin(x)` is undefined (or as your error suggests "too large" because the package plots it numerically) . You can solve this problem by using `restrict y to domain`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
  restrict y to domain=-10:10,
  mark=none,
  domain=-360:360,
  samples=500,
  smooth}, % All plots: 50 samples, smooth, no marks
  axis x line=middle,
  axis y line=center,
  xmin=-360,
  xmax=360,
  ymin=-10,
  ymax=10,
  enlargelimits=upper] % extend the axes a bit to the right and top
  \addplot {1/sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```